# permutation - seating three professions around a table

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a permutations question I'm struggling with.

I have 9 doctors, 7 engineers and 3 mechanics seated at a round table.  How many possible ways to seat them all so that no two people of the same profession seat next to each other (on either side).  Arrangements are considered same if everyone has same neighbors on both sides

Thank you!

Comment: Can you tell us what part are you struggling with the most?

Comment: Often a good start is to consider the placement of one type first.  How many ways can the doctors be seated? (assume that, say, the first doctor, $d_1$, always takes a given seat.  That takes care of the rotational symmetry).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to tell us what you know, show us what you have attempted, and explain where you are stuck.